# Toggle TextWrapping in TextBox inside FlipView

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I have a FlipView where each FlipViewItem contains a TextBox bound to an ObservableCollection and I need to toggle TextWrapping for the TextBox's that are inside the FlipView.

I have tried everything I could think of and no help online thus far. Not a single result I could find.

How can I do this?

XAML:

...

```
// This part is for the AppBar Toggle button
<ToggleButton x:Name="wordWrapToggleButton" Style="{StaticResource WordWrapAppBarButtonStyle}" />
```

...

```
// For the FlipView
<FlipView x:Name="flipView" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0, 50, 0, 0" ItemsSource="{Binding Note, Mode=TwoWay}" Loaded="flipView_Loaded" SelectionChanged="flipView_SelectionChanged" FontSize="12.667">
    <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Contents, Mode=TwoWay}" Tag="{Binding Title, Mode=TwoWay}" TextWrapping="{Binding ElementName=wordWrapToggleButton, Path=.CheckState, Mode=TwoWay}" IsSpellCheckEnabled="True" AcceptsReturn="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" FontSize="{Binding ElementName=flipView, Path=FontSize, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
</FlipView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a [binding converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding.converter.aspx/css) that converts from `bool` to `TextWrapping`

```
public class BooleanToTextWrappingConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return (value is bool && (bool)value) ? TextWrapping.Wrap : TextWrapping.NoWrap;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return value is TextWrapping && (TextWrapping)value == TextWrapping.Wrap;
    }
}
```

and use that in your binding

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:BooleanToTextWrappingConverter x:Key="BooleanToTextWrappingConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>
...
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Contents, Mode=TwoWay}"
        TextWrapping="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=wordWrapToggleButton,
                       Converter={StaticResource BooleanToTextWrappingConverter}}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

---

Note that the `TextWrapping` binding isn't two-way, as that makes no sense.

Comment: I had a feeling that's what I needed to do, but sometimes explaining my thoughts just makes things even more confusing for people. Thanks for your help @Clemens :-)

Comment: I have just one more question if you don't mind; The code you provided is giving me an `Error 1 The name "BooleanToTextWrappingConverter" does not exist in the namespace "using:myapp".` and `Error 2 The type 'local:BooleanToTextWrappingConverter' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.`..

Comment: and  and `Error 3 The type or namespace name 'BooleanToTextWrappingConverter' does not exist in the namespace 'myapp' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`and `Error 4 The type 'myapp.MainPage' already contains a definition for 'BooleanToTextWrappingConverter'`. Any idea what that actually means? I searched online but the results were related to different IValueConverters and I couldn't make much sense of it.

Comment: In the code example I assume that the XAML `xmlns:local=...` namespace declaration in your Page references the namespace of the `BooleanToTextWrappingConverter` class. If it's in a different namespace, you have to write another `xmlns:...` declaration.

Comment: Oh sorry about that. I mistakenly placed the code in the wrong place in code-behind. It's working great now, thanks so much for your help! :-)